# How to get birthday list contacts from iphone

Tags: iphone, addressbook

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef nameArray = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople (addressBook);

m_SourceContactsUserArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i<CFArrayGetCount(nameArray); i++) {
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(nameArray, i);
    NSString *personName = (NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    [m_SourceContactsUserArray addObject:personName];
}
CFRelease(addressBook);
CFRelease(nameArray);
```

Comment: Could please explain what is the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this code:

```
ABAddressBookRef myAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *allPeople = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(myAddressBook);

for (id record in allPeople) {
    NSMutableDictionary *newRecord = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    CFTypeRef bDayProperty = ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonBirthdayProperty);

    if (ABRecordCopyValue((ABRecordRef)record, kABPersonBirthdayProperty)) 
           {
        NSDate *date=(NSDate*)bDayProperty;
        [newRecord setObject:date forKey:@"birthDate"];
        date=nil;
        [date release]; 
    }
   CFRelease(myAddressBook);
 }
```

it will help you.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following to obtain a `CFDateRef` for the person's birthday:

```
CFDateRef date = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonBirthdayProperty);
```